# Can't access RetryContext on the ExecutionContext

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How is it that we can't access RetryContext on the ExecutionContext on a Azure Function?

```
        try
        {
            //my code here....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (executionContext.RetryContext?.RetryCount)
        }
```

The RetryContext property is not there? WTF?!

Comment: You need to provide more info. How did you inject the execution context? What Azure Function version and .net version are you using?

Comment: Sorry @PeterBons my bad :(

.NET 6.0

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4736 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.8.1.18957

The execution context is injected on it's on by .net

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. When I inject the `ExecutionContext` I can access the property.

Answer (score 0):

*Please check the below steps if it helps to fix the issue*:

1. In .NET 6 Azure Functions (v4), `RetryContext` is available as part of `FunctionContext`/`ExecutionContext` as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.functioncontext.retrycontext?view=azure-dotnet).

- It can be accessible using the Namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker`.

[image]

- The Same Property `RetryContext` is part of the `ExecutionContext` when it comes to non-dotnet languages as given in the [GitHub Repos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7048#issuecomment-771030768) of Azure Functions Host Retry Context include proposal.

Comment: This doesn't help _answer_ the question. Yep, that info is correct -> but it's not explaining how this causes the `RetryCount` property to throw a NRE. This issue seems to be how the underlying `_retryContext` values passed to the ctor .. isn't actually getting passed to the ctor.